# Read different xml Nodes with same names

Tags: xml, vb.net, nodes

for the following xml

```
<Student>
<Name>Marc</Name>
<Age>20</Age>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Age>30</Age>
</Student>
```

I'm trying to run a code to go throught all the objects Student.

What I did so far is (taking into account xmldoc is my xmlDocuemtn variable)

```
Dim AllStudentNodes = xmldoc.Selectnodes("/Student")

For each item in AllStudentNodes

Name = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Student/Name").InnerText

Next
```

What happens it is that it will only go take the first student name twice if there are two nodes named Student, three if there are three Nodes named Student..

It seems like it will get stuck on the first node as many times and Student nodes there are, even if those are different, it won't iterate through all of them.

Any suggestions?

Code

```
xmlDoc.Load(Request.InputStream)
xmlCXMLNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("cXML")

     Dim ItemOutNodes = xmlCXMLNode.SelectNodes("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut")

                For Each Item In ItemOutNodes

                    Try
                        Node_IO_LineNumber = Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut").Attributes("lineNumber")
                        IO_LineNumber = GetInnerText(Node_IO_LineNumber)
                        Node_IO_Quantity = Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut").Attributes("quantity")
                        IO_Quantity = GetInnerText(Node_IO_Quantity)
                        Node_IO_RequestedDeliverYDate = Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut").Attributes("requestedDeliveryDate")
                        IO_RequestedDeliveryDate = GetInnerText(Node_IO_RequestedDeliverYDate).Split("+")
                        IO_RequestedDeliveryDateInsert = IO_RequestedDeliveryDate(0).Replace("T", " ")
                        Node_IO_IID_SupplierPartID = Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut/ItemID/SupplierPartID")
                        IO_IID_SupplierPartID = GetInnerText(Node_IO_IID_SupplierPartID)
                        IO_IID_SupplierPartID = IO_IID_SupplierPartID.Replace("#", "Ñ")
                        Node_IO_IID_BuyerPartID = Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut/ItemID/BuyerPartID")
                        IO_IID_BuyerPartID = GetInnerText(Node_IO_IID_BuyerPartID)
                        Node_IO_ID_UP_Money = Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut/ItemDetail/UnitPrice/Money")
                        IO_ID_UP_Money = GetInnerText(Node_IO_ID_UP_Money)
                        Node_IO_ID_Descrption = Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut/ItemDetail/Description")
                        IO_ID_Description = GetInnerText(Node_IO_ID_Descrption)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Response.Write("Error ItemOut")
                        ErrorFound = True
                        ErrorString = ErrorString + "-Error ItemOut"
                    End Try
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you actually request the first node matching the XPath in the whole document.
You need to find your `Name` element within the currently iterated `item`.

First thing which is need to mentionted is that your XML is not valid.
XML must have single root element.

Let's assume you have the following document:

```
<root>
<Student>
<Name>Marc</Name>
<Age>20</Age>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Age>30</Age>
</Student>
</root>
```

Then, you can do it this way:

```
Dim AllStudentNodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("root/Student")

For each item in AllStudentNodes

Name = item.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText

Next
```

Note that it is `item.SelectSingleNode`, not `xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode`.
I.e., "find the single name in my `item`", not "find the single (first) name in my whole document".

Here is the **[working .NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xbRWeC).**

**Update:**

In your code you use the following XPath:

```
Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut").Attributes("lineNumber")
Item.SelectSingleNode("/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut/ItemDetail/UnitPrice/Money")
```

which is absolute XPath and actually means "**from the root** find the first element matching cXML/Request...". So, slash in the beginning makes it search from root document as well.
Your XPath should be relative. Since your `Item` is already `ItemOut`, it can be simply:

```
Item.Attributes("lineNumber")
Item.SelectSingleNode("ItemDetail/UnitPrice/Money")
```

It is as simple as folder structure or URL.
You open `example.com/ItemOut` URL and if you meet a relative link like `ItemDetail.html`, then it will open `example.com/ItemOut/ItemDetail.html`. If you place a slash in the beginning like `/ItemDetail.html`, it will open absolute `example.com/ItemDetail.html`.

Comment: Hello man I tried that and I see it in th demo working but its weird what its happening.

When I look into the object item I can see the InnerXML being "Marc,20" which is fine, the second time is "Peter,30" which is fine as well, but the variable Name is still Marc all the time! 

Even if the object inner xml is "Petter,30".

I load the variable as that

name = Item.SelectSingleNode("/Student/Name").InnerText


But even if the object 'item' is correctly lodead it keeps taking the name Marc, what the hell?

Comment: @AlejandroA Show the code you are using now, and which gives these results.

Comment: There you go, at the end of post. Getinnertext is a function I made to check if node exists and take the innertext if so.

Comment: @AlejandroA Oh, I see. Please, check the updated answer.

Comment: Works now! Thank you very much, giving your answer as valid

Answer (score 0):

Yeldar´s answer is fine but I´lll show you an alternative way using `XElement` instead of XmlDocument.
I prefer `XElement` due to the fancy VB .NET syntax and full Linq support:

```
    Dim xml as XElement = <Students>
                              <Student>
                                  <Name>Marc</Name>
                                  <Age>20</Age>
                              </Student>
                              <Student>
                                  <Name>Peter</Name>
                                  <Age>30</Age>
                              </Student>
                          </Students>
    'OR if you have/want to use XmlDocument:' 
    Dim xmlDoc = New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("YourXmlAsString")
    xml = XElement.Load(xmlDoc.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree)

    Dim studentNames As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xml.<Student>.<Name>
    'Also possible:' 
    studentNames = xml...<Name>

    For Each name In studentNames
           Console.WriteLine(name.Value)
    Next
```